# SQL Query: get the date and customerid of the most expensive order placed

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone help me with a mySQL query? My data is:

```
| OrderID | ItemPrice |
|---------|-----------|
|       1 |      2500 |
|       2 |       500 |

| OrderID | CustomerID |    OrderDate |
|---------|------------|--------------|
|       1 |          1 | 30-June-2017 |
|       2 |          1 |  2-July-2017 |

| FirstName | CustomerID |
|-----------|------------|
|      John |          1 |
|      Jane |          2 |
```

I'm trying to get the date and customerid of the most expensive order placed.

I can do parts of it, but am just interested in what the most efficient query would be.

In my efforts to do this, I've gotten this far:

I can get the orderID for the highest price with this query:

```
SELECT OrderID from `LineItem` ORDER BY ItemPrice DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Lets say Is ave the value of the above query as 'x', I could get the name with:

```
SELECT FirstName from `Order` o, `LineItem` l, `Customer` c where o.OrderID = x and o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID;
```

But I'm not sure how the chain the two commands together, or if this approach would be the most efficient option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use subqueries.

```
select customerid, orderdate
from lineitem l
inner join customner c
  on l.CustomerID = c.CustomerID;
where orderid in (SELECT OrderID from `LineItem` ORDER BY ItemPrice DESC LIMIT 1)
            ^^^^^^
```

as you can see, your first statement is subquery for orderId

Comment: thanks,  I'm trying to test it online with https://paiza.io/projects/AU5qrg8L6dqewPdiaKZB5g?language=mysql   , you can see the table creation data (i tested its working with ```SELECT * FROM `LineItem`;```) but I keep getting an ```ERROR 1235 (42000) at line 57: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'``` error.  I had been working with MySQL5.6 on SQLFIDDLE too and got that same error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d318b